# Creating a key-value class

Tags: python

I have this dictionary class

```
class my_key_value(dict): 
    def __init__(self): 
        self = dict() 
    def add(self, key, value): 
        self[key] = value
```

I can add items such as

```
my_dict = my_key_value()
my_dict.add("hello", 0)
```

I would like to increment the value for the keys based on some conditions. Assume `fp` is a file handler, then

```
for line in fp:
    if word in line:
        my_dict.inc(word)
```

Should increment the value of `word`. The following function definition is wrong

```
def inc(self, key):
    self[key] = value+1
```

May I know how to fix that?

Comment: Why are you doing this? This adds no functionality over the built-in dict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't define `value`. Set it to `self[key]`:

```
def inc(self, key):
    value = self[key]
    self[key] = value+1
```

Answer (score 3):

You never set `value`, so `value + 1` is meaningless.

You can use the built-in `+=` operator.

```
def inc(self, key):
    self[key] += 1
```